# How to get a try/catch error in Javascript when file doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, css, file, try-catch

I replace a background image using Javascript in an element by calling a **local** file (not a URL).

I want to try to catch an error if this file does not exist.

So I tried the following code:

```
    try {
        thing.style.backgroundImage = str;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        thing.style.backgroundImage = "none";
    }
```

However, even nonesense file names seem to pass and no error is generated. Even worse, sometimes the background image displayed is empty and sometimes it is an image from a previous call.

Is there any way to try/catch an error here?

Comment: The image is loaded asynchronously, so you can't get an error.

Comment: If you were loading it into an `Image` object you could use its `onerror` property to call a function. I'm not sure how you would do the equivalent with a style.

Comment: @Barmar, could you give me some example code to try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd take [Barmar's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335961/how-to-get-a-try-catch-error-in-javascript-when-file-doesnt-exist#comment45018047_28335961) and use an [`Image()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement.Image) to get the image. If you do that, you don't really need a try-catch; you can just call the appropriate function to set the background image.

You could do something like this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "pathToImage";

img.onerror = function(){ // Failed to load
    thing.style.backgroundImage = "none";
};
img.onload = function(){ // Loaded successfully
    thing.style.backgroundImage = img.src;
};
```

Comment: This basically works! The one puzzle I have is that setting thing.style.backgroundImage = img.src didn't seem to load the image. But when I entered my original str it did work. My original str was of the form url(<file location>). I tried variations of including the url, escaping and not escaping, etc. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @lynvie That's odd; it might have something to do with relative URL paths (the way that the file is being accessed relative to your current location in the directory).

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a browser-specific bug? I'm using Chrome. Anyways, your method seems to work for try/catch. Thanks!

Comment: Just in case anyone was wondering -- I had to escape the slash (but not the space) in my filename calls for img.src. But for the actual backgroundImage call, I had to escape both the slash and the space.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using AJAX instead of creating image objects and binding event listeners to the image's error and load events. 
While using AJAX, you could also rely on the status codes if you are using a service, or something that gives you dynamic images, it depends on how you want to manipulate everything.

Check out this bin, and see if it works for your use case.

http://jsbin.com/tezabupeli/18/edit?js,output